# IS it possible to use dpdk without kernel modules?

Tags: linux, dpdk

Is there a way to use dpdk without `igb_uio` module or other `kni`, `vfio` modules ? also without the `uio_pci_generic` module ?

I mean can dpdk just work fine with the normal (kernel space drivers) like `ixgbe` directly.

I have tried binding 2 interfaces with `ixgbe` using dpdk's dev-bind python script:

```
Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:04:00.0 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb' if=p3p1 drv=ixgbe unused=uio_pci_generic
0000:04:00.1 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb' if=p3p2 drv=ixgbe unused=uio_pci_generic
```

But my app exited with the following fatal error:

```
rte_eth_dev_count_avail() returned 0
```

Thank you

Comment: You seem to already know the answer.  ixgbe will only transfer data between your Intel card and a kernel buffer.

Comment: were you able to run with pcap/af_packet/af_xdp to the ixgbe driver in DPDK without uio_pci_generic/igb_uio/vfio?

Answer (score 1):

One can use DPDK without kernel by using PMD for TAP/TUN/PCAP/XDP. In these scenarios neither uio_pci_generic/igb_uio/vfio-pci or DPDK KNI not used. Hence without DPDK kernel modules one can run for interfaces.

For your particular use case where NIC is using `ixgbe`, please use AF_PAACKET/AF_XDP mode.